# Uncaught syntax error unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting the syntax error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

from this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        });
        function($) {
            $(".scroll").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},900);
            });
        });
</script>
```

What kinds of mistakes produce this Javascript Syntax error?

Comment: `function($) {` that's not valid

Comment: put your code in dom ready as well

Comment: there is no `function($) {` do you mean `$(function(){` ?

Comment: thank you @Ted , that was the problem

Comment: @Shelly - check my answer, that isn't the only problem. the event needs to be within document ready otherwise you might miss some elements

Comment: @Shelly, generally speaking, it's appropriate to upvote helpful answers to the questions you ask. Both of the answers below answer your question. It's also appropriate to mark one answer as correct, assuming it's correct. I also suggest cleaning up some of the questions you've asked in the past, as most have not been answered, or have been solved in the comments.

Comment: @JamesHill sorry for the late up vote i was desperate at that time, i will  make sure to up vote and accept the answers  in the future whn i ask questions thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".scroll").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},900);
   });
});
```

also, there is no `function($) {`, do you mean `$(function(){`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `function($) {` at all (the syntax is incorrect anyway):

```
$(document).ready(function () {{
  $(".scroll").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 900);
  });
});
```

As others have mentioned, your event handler should be inside the `$( document ).ready()` function.

Here's some more information on [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).